# How to Get SQLExpress Virtual Path

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the virtual path for some reason ....\ isn't working to navigate through the directory.

```
SqlConnection sqlConnectionCmdString = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=..\..\database\ClientRegit.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

Comment: Stop using `AttachDbFileName`. Why are you using this deprecated feature?

Comment: How would you write the string with out the AttachDbFilename

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\database\ClientRegit.mdf
```

Comment: I need the virtual path of the data directory

Comment: I am not in the c:\AppDirectory folder I am not using .Net project I need substitution for a Win app program

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection sqlConnectionCmdString = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="+ Application.StartupPath+ @"\database\ClientRegit.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

Comment: where \database is gives me unrecognized escape sequence